# bower-asset Failed to download bower-asset/jquery-ui

Tags: composer-php, bower

i try to install composer libs from scratch, and had an error:
[image]

Try to fix it by:

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"`

`composer self-update`

`composer clear-cache`

As you see, I`m not good in it, and also I am desperate, because i don`t know what is really going on, and how to fix this

**UPD** Also try `composer install --prefer-source`. But it not helps
Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291681/the-lock-file-is-not-up-to-date-with-the-latest-changes-in-composer-json) is not copy, because there was conclusion, and i my case there was broken link inside `composer.lock`.

Comment: You may need to run `composer update` - your `composer.lock` seems to have links to non-existing sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291681/the-lock-file-is-not-up-to-date-with-the-latest-changes-in-composer-json)

Comment: @NicoHaase, look on answer below)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was finded by @rob006

So, i try to `composer install`, and have an error on img

**My worked desicion was:**
 - `composer update myLibVendorName/myLibSourceName` - right after i get an error.