# I get error while run composer install at live server

Tags: laravel, ssh, composer-php

When I try to run `composer update` | `composer install` | `composer require`, I got this error on the Production server:

```
  composer install 
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may 
  be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
  Package operations: 19 installs, 55 updates, 0 removals

  In Filesystem.php line 182:

 /var/www/html/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper does not exist and could not be created.  


  install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom- 
  installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|-- 
  verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [-- 
  ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: run with `sudo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291681/the-lock-file-is-not-up-to-date-with-the-latest-changes-in-composer-json

Comment: not the same, this gives me `/var/www/html/vendor/kylekatarnls/update-helper does not exist `

Comment: can't use sudo with composer this bad command @Hossein

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeException vendor does not exist and could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created)